# Bound for the maximum of an array where we distribute (greedily) to minimise the maximum value at each iteration

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Apologies for the verbose title. Consider an array of length $N$ containing only zeros initially. At each step, we increase the smallest two elements of the array by $w_1$ and $w_2$ respectively (where $w_1 > w_2$).

I wish to bound $M_i$, the maximum of the array after $i$ steps.

Aside from trivial bounds, I wondered if it was possible to attain instead (an equivalent) bound on the distance above the "eqi-distribution". That is the value at step $i$ instead we try to bound: $M_i - \frac{(w_1 + w_2)i}{2N}$. (For example, after $2N$ steps each element of the array having value $w_1+w_2$ would be eqi-distributed)

However, I still struggled to find concrete bounds however I believe they have dependence on $w_1 - w_2$.

I'm looking for either a bound, or a field of research that may provide more useful tools for this kind of problem.